# How can one extract a list of supported languages from an iOS .ipa file?

Tags: ios, locale, reverse-engineering, ipa

I have a bunch of .ipa files (compiled iOS apps).

I want to extract the list of languages supported by each of them.

I >think< I can do this by finding directories with names like:

```
Payload/<app_name>.app/<locale>.lproj/
```

in each .ipa file.

Is that correct?

Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you trying to do this on the iOS device? Or on the Mac?

Comment: I will be processing the .ipa files on an OS X or GNU/Linux server.

Comment: Some links that support my *.lproj theory - http://bugs.yoyogames.com/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=9985 - https://forums.adobe.com/message/3976882